# Issue with placement of onload function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'd really love some advice on the best way to re-structure the below function. What I am doing is setting up the file reader and refreshing several divs content in a for loop. Basically, my code works perfectly as long as I leave in the bottom alert saying `alert(sparespacetofill);` for testing, but when I take this alert out, my div's content do not get refreshed as should. Its obviously a problem with the `reader.onload` function not getting called before the function finishes running, but I really am stuck on how I should structure this differently.

```
function setup_reader(file,number, sparespacetofill) {

var name = file.name;
var reader = new FileReader();
 
reader.onload = function(e) { 
$('#' + sparespacetofill).children('img').attr('src',e.target.result); 
                                   
if ($('#' + sparespacetofill).find("p").length <= 0 && sparespacetofill !='pic0' ) {
$('#' + sparespacetofill).append('<p id="deleteit">Delete<a></p>');  
}
               
}
   
reader.readAsDataURL(file);

//alert(sparespacetofill);///ISSUE IS IN HERE IF I UNCOMMENT THIS OUT

return sparespacetofill;  
}
```

Comment: could you try onloadend() instead of onload?

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=4DqX_0Cz_6l maybe this helps

Comment: Tried onloadend, and adding the closure as per link but still no joy?

Comment: It might be helpful to see the code that calls `setup_reader()`, and to see the code, if any, that runs after the function returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the onload event fires, has the Ajax operation completely finished?

If so, whatever functionality you're trying to perform when the function returns, instead perform it at the end of the onload function. Call a function there that continues on with whatever code you were running.

Reorganize the code as needed so it can be split into two parts: the part that runs before setup_reader() and that calls setup_reader(), and the part that runs after the onload event fires.

Comment: Hi Matt, ive done that with a function i.e. : setup_reader(file, i, sparespacetofill);

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but it might not be reasonable to rely on the setup_reader function return to initiate the next step in the code (since the onload event hasn't fired yet). Instead of continuing on with the next step when the function returns, continue on at the end of the onload event handler, by calling a function there to run whatever code that still needs to be run.

Comment: Excellent, that did the trick, combined with a closure on the onload with help from Simons link above. Thanks for all guys, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can try Javascript setTimeout() Method like this,

```
setTimeout(return sparespacetofill, 3000) ;
```

// Instead of this lines

```
alert(sparespacetofill);///ISSUE IS IN HERE IF I UNCOMMENT THIS OUT

return sparespacetofill;
```